# MDriven: Transient instance of persistent class

Tags: transient, mdriven

In MDriven I have a persistent class that I need to create a transient instance of.

Is this possible?

I do know that a workaround would be to create as usual and then discard it.

Clarification 2018-02-02 17:04 UTC+1:
I would need to do this without adding anything to the model, compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct - it is not possible to change a class to become transient in runtime.

You can however subclass it... And make the subclass transient... I have had that exact need myself and solved it that way.

[image: The MonthDemandSupplyCorrection is persistent - but the MDSC_Placeholder is not]

Example: The MonthDemandSupplyCorrection is persistent - but the MDSC_Placeholder is not

**Update**: Since the requirement was clarified to be "not known in design time" - a better answer is to create an ordinary instance and avoid saving it. This can be ensured with the undo-service and memory transactions like this:

```
  EcoSpace.Undo.StartTransaction();
  try
  {
     //Any changes you need
  }
  finally
  {
    EcoSpace.Undo.RollbackTransaction(); 
  }
```

Comment: An example or details of "how to" would be great, thanks! I'll mark it as correct answer then. :-)

Comment: Oh, a bit of a misunderstanding. I need it "ad hoc", not in the model. :-) Any way to do it "on the fly", i.e. in runtime?

Comment: Aha - no sorry - then you are left with your own suggestion; create a normal object and avoid saving it. Consider using a in-memory transaction to accomplish this . updating the answer for this

Answer (score 0):

You can try umlrt -  work with model,  classes,  etc at runtime. As an example -  https://www.capableobjects.com/2016/07/21/calling-your-own-c-net-things-from-turnkeyserver-side/

Migth help -  old free ebook -  The ECO III book
Written by Alois Schmid